# On derivation of the hypergeometric function

Tags: hypergeometric-function

The generalised [hypergeometric function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) is of the form:

> $$_{p}F_{q}(a_{1},...,a_{p};b_{1},...,b_{q};x)$$

This is also represented as a hypergeometric series.

How was this function derived?

Comment: Do you know first the way Gauss derived the "historical" hypergeometric function ?

Comment: If *was derived* means how to compute the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$ see http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.3